# Printed Array table comes out multiple times

Tags: c, arrays

When I execute my code I keep getting the right answers but it is printed multiple times? I want it display a table with with 5 columns and 3 rows and there should be 4 of these tables but I get three times too many and I don't know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>



int main(){
    int w;
    int n = 1;
    int i;
    for(w = 1; w < 5; w++){
        FILE *myFile;
        float numberArray[1];
        if(n == 4){
            myFile = fopen("input4.txt", "r");
            n++;
        }
        if(n == 3){
           myFile = fopen("input3.txt", "r");
           n++;
        }
        if(n == 2){
           myFile = fopen("input2.txt", "r");
           n++;
        }
        if(n == 1){
           myFile = fopen("input1.txt", "r");   
           n++;
        }


        if (myFile == NULL)
        {
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit (0);
        }


        printf("Enter 3 numbers between 0 and 9.999:\n");
        printf("Number      sin      cos      tan      atan\n");
        printf("-------------------------------------------\n");

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
        fscanf(myFile, "%f,", &numberArray[i] );
        }   

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
        printf("%.6f    %.4f    %.4f    %.4f    %.4f\n",numberArray[i], sin(numberArray[i]), cos(numberArray[i]), tan(numberArray[i]), atan(numberArray[i]));
        }

        fclose(myFile);

    }
return 0;

}
```

Comment: You are reading and writing in unallocated memory space when accessing `numberArray`. You defined `numberArray[1]` with a size of 1, yet you are accessing `numberArray[2..3]` in your loops.

Comment: Why don't you use `w` in your `if()` tests instead of `n`?

Comment: @Cubia he's not accessing `numberArray[3]`, just `numberArray[2]`.

Comment: @Cubia You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading and writing in unallocated memory space when accessing numberArray.

You defined numberArray[1] with a size of 1, yet you are accessing numberArray[1..2] in your loops here :

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
fscanf(myFile, "%f,", &numberArray[i] );
}   

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
printf("%.6f    %.4f    %.4f    %.4f    %.4f\n",numberArray[i], sin(numberArray[i]), cos(numberArray[i]), tan(numberArray[i]), atan(numberArray[i]));
}
```

I have not tested your code, but this seems to be the most obvious culprit.